# Counter Intuitive javascript sqrt performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm taking a webDev class and one of the tasks we had to do was calculate if an age was a perfect square.  Seeing some of the different solutions students came up with, I was curious about actual performance so I wrote up a little test to see how they stack up to each other, and it turns out the one with the most calls to Math. functions is far and away the fastest consistently.

Here are the functions:

```
var func1 = function(age){
  var ageSq = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(age)) * Math.floor(Math.sqrt(age));
  return ageSq === age;
}
var func2 = function(age){
  return Math.sqrt(age) % 1 === 0;
}
var func3 = function(age){
  return Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(age));
}
var func4 = function(age){
  return (parseInt(Math.sqrt(age)) * parseInt(Math.sqrt(age)) == age)
}
```

Running each of these over a 100,000 array of Integers from 0-99 total time from each is as follows for 3 runs:

```
[4.405000000000015, 8.625000000000014, 10.54000000000002, 7.895000000000039]
[3.989999999999807, 6.310000000000002, 6.780000000000001, 6.444999999999993]
[3.584999999999795, 13.98500000000014, 11.47999999999999, 9.965000000000003]
```

As you can see the first one is dramatically faster - but just looking at the code I would have guessed it would be the slowest.  Any idea what's going on here under the hood?

Comment: Those benchmarks won't be terribly accurate, thanks to the JIT compilation that JS runtimes use. You need to use something like jsperf to warm up the VM and make sure the code has been thoroughly compiled before the real speed will be observable. I imagine the JITter will inline most of the `Math` calls here, but `sqrt` is so insanely slow on its own that it won't really matter.

Comment: if Math.sqrt() is insanely slow then calling it twice (algorithm 1) might be expected to dominate and make it slower than 2 & 3, no?

Comment: @djna unless the JIT compiler is inlining it. Given how simple these functions are, I bet it's hoisting the `sqrt` call and maybe even the `parseInt` call and only executing them once. The runtime is more than happy to deduplicate calls that it knows are pure (have no side effects). The `Math` functions are fantastic candidates for that.

Comment: That `parseInt` solution is horrible. Don't cast numbers to strings only to parse them to numbers.

Comment: @ssube, thanks.  I'd thought about inlining, not about de-duplication.

Comment: On the rare occasion where the VM a) knows the function is pure and b) can prove the parameters are the same, it might be able to move that call up before the others. In this case, `var tmp = Math.sqrt(age); return (tmp * tmp) == age`.

Comment: @ssube - you're right about the benchmarks being off.  This was using window.performance.now() and I retried it using the same function 4 times and there was a significant difference between them.